# 'list' object has no attribute 'get' - GraphQL Python

Tags: python, django, dictionary, graphql

I followed this simple example on how graphql auth works with sendgrid...I literaly copied all the code and setup all the files. Here - > https://blog.learningdollars.com/2019/10/14/how-to-confirm-emails-on-your-django-graphql-api-using-sendgrid/

After i run the mutation createUser i got error '**list' object has no attribute 'get'**

schema.py

```
import graphene
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from graphene_django import DjangoObjectType
from graphql_jwt.utils import jwt_encode, jwt_payload
from .models import User
from .send_email import send_confirmation_email


class UserType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = User


class CreateUser(graphene.Mutation):
    message = graphene.String()
    user = graphene.Field(UserType)

    class Arguments:
        username = graphene.String()
        email = graphene.String(required=True)
        password = graphene.String(required=True)

    def mutate(self, info, username, email, password):
        user = User(
            email=email,
            username=username,
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        send_confirmation_email(email=user.email, username=user.username)
        return CreateUser(user=user, message="Successfully created user, {}".format(user.username))


class LoginUser(graphene.Mutation):
    user = graphene.Field(UserType)
    message = graphene.String()
    token = graphene.String()
    verification_prompt = graphene.String()

    class Arguments:
        email = graphene.String()
        password = graphene.String()

    def mutate(self, info, **kwargs):
        email = kwargs.get('email')
        password = kwargs.get('password')
        user = authenticate(username=email, password=password)
        error_message = 'Invalid login credentials'
        success_message = "You logged in successfully."
        verification_error = 'Your email is not verified'
        if user:
            if user.is_verified:
                payload = jwt_payload(user)
                token = jwt_encode(payload)
                return LoginUser(token=token, message=success_message)
            return LoginUser(message=verification_error)
        return LoginUser(message=error_message)


class Mutation(graphene.ObjectType):
    create_user = CreateUser.Field()
    login_user = LoginUser.Field()
```

Its a simple model User with some mutations inside of that schema file.
I know that dict cant have get method but I cant spot a mistake in that code.
The major issue is that i copied all the code from that tutorial and I didnt changed anything.

***EDIT:***

I just spoted a mistake its in send_mail.py

I needed to remove [email] and import  **from sendgrid.helpers.mail import Mail, Email**

Now i can create user without error but problem is that i dont get email on my mail account. Sendgrid wont work.

After that i tried to run python send_email.py file and i got another error.

**from dota.settings import SECRET_KEY, DOMAIN, SENDGRID_API_KEY
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dota'**

https://prnt.sc/rajz6c

And my settings file where i put SECRET_KEY, DOMAIN and SENDGRID_APIKEY is in dota folder. I dont know why it wont import it like it should.

send_mail.py

```
import jwt
from sendgrid import SendGridAPIClient
from sendgrid.helpers.mail import Mail, Email
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from dota.settings import SECRET_KEY, DOMAIN, SENDGRID_API_KEY


def send_confirmation_email(email, username):
    token = jwt.encode({'user': username}, SECRET_KEY,
                       algorithm='HS256').decode('utf-8')
    context = {
        'small_text_detail': 'Thank you for '
                             'creating an account. '
                             'Please verify your email '
                             'address to set up your account.',
        'email': email,
        'domain': DOMAIN,
        'token': token,
    }
    # locates our email.html in the templates folder
    msg_html = render_to_string('email.html', context)
    message = Mail(
        # the email that sends the confirmation email
        from_email=Email('example@gmail.com'),
        to_email=Email('veljko33614@its.edu.rs'),  # list of email receivers
        subject='Account activation',  # subject of your email
        content=msg_html
    )
    try:
        sg = SendGridAPIClient(apikey=SENDGRID_API_KEY)
        sg.send(message)
    except Exception as e:
        return str(e)
```

Error Traceback:

C:\Users\Veljko\Desktop\Desktop\Dev\dota2-api\users>python send_email.py

**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "send_email.py", line 5, in 
    from dota.settings import SECRET_KEY, DOMAIN, SENDGRID_API_KEY
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dota'**

Comment: Can you add the whole error traceback?

Comment: Yes, give me a sec

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "send_email.py", line 5, in <module>
    from dota.settings import SECRET_KEY, DOMAIN, SENDGRID_API_KEY
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dota'

Comment: and my settings.py file is in dota folder...So basiclly thats how i imported SECRET_KEY, DOMAIN and SENDGRID_APIKEY, but i get this error.

Comment: What is the directory that your `dota` is located in? Is this your project root directory?

Comment: its in root directory as main directory

Comment: main app, but also i have users app and heroes app separated...from users i want to access settings in dota directory but it gives me that error module not found

Comment: You could use [django-graphql-auth](https://django-graphql-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for registration and authentication with django and graphql. It sends email for user verification and already has implemented the password reset and a lot of other mutations.

Comment: I know but I tried this variation with sendgird

Comment: You can use django-graphql-auth with sendgrid using the [django-anymail-package](https://github.com/anymail/django-anymail)

Comment: Ok I will check that